# My android head stopped triggering breakpoints

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin.android, uno-platform

I recently updated the Android app to Android 10, had to disable Shared Runtime to get the app even running, and it stopped triggering on breakpoints. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this happens you can check the following:

- Your packaging mode is set to `APK` and not `AAB`
- Delete your bin/obj folder, uninstall the application from the device/simulator, then restart Visual Studio.
- If it still does not work, try disabling "Fast Deploy" in the project options